# RabbitMQ to Azure Event Hub: AMQP 0.9.1 compatibility with AMQP 1.0

Tags: azure, rabbitmq, amqp, azure-eventhub

I have a component that currently integrated with RabbitMQ. I would like to swap out RabbitMQ for Azure Event Hub as we are now in the cloud. Is AMQP 0.9.1 compatible with AMQP 1.0? Will the swap work seamlessly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMQP 1.0 is very different to 0.9x. They are not compatible. However, it is likely that your code is transport independent, in which case it does not really matter, you just swap out one implementation for the other.

It is also important to note is that RabbitMQ is a brokered messaging service whist EventHubs are persistent streams of data read via consumer groups. The two are quite different technologies in how you deal with the payload. Messages are not equal to events. Azure Service Bus is a closer fit to RabbitMQ.

If you are working at the protocol level, there is a AMQP 1.0 plug in for RabbitMQ ([See here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-amqp1.0)) and you should be able to shovel messages across from RabbitMQ to Azure Service Bus using a bridge.